# Update cart with WooCommerce ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce website, I have changed the cart page, removed the button "update cart" and create 2 buttons to add and remove items of product like I show in this picture:

[image]

When I click on the quantity buttons I want to call the same function if I press the button to update the cart.

For this I am using ajax but it doesn't do anything.

First in my `function.php` file I have this:

```
  function update_my_cart() {
    // here update then cart
    var_dump("execute");
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_my_cart', 'update_my_cart' );    // If called from admin panel
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_my_cart', 'update_my_cart' );  



    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rct_enqueue_scripts' );

    if ( ! function_exists( 'rct_enqueue_scripts' ) ) :

    function rct_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'rct-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/themeCoffee.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script('rct-js', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    }

    endif;
```

And in my jquery file I have this:

```
  updatecart = function(qty) {
    var currentVal, data, item_hash, request;
    currentVal = void 0;
    data = void 0;
    item_hash = void 0;
    currentVal = parseFloat(qty);
    request = $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax_object.ajax_url',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        quantity: currentVal,
        action: 'update_my_cart'
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
      alert('cart update ');
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
    });
  };
```

I obtain this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Because I try to load `my_website/cart/ajax_object.ajax_url`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec I already modified my file  like you suggest. and change the question with the new change but I still receive the same error. Any idea!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  I have a mistake I have  this in my ajax function url: 'ajax_object.ajax_url', and the correct is without  quotes. Now works, thanks you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have forget this essential process:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_ajax_scripts'); 

function add_my_ajax_scripts() {
    // Here you register your script located in a subfolder `js` of your active theme
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    // Here you are going to make the bridge between php and js
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'cart_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

Then you will retrieve "`ajaxurl`" and "`cart_ajax`" in your javascript file in "`url:`":

```
$.ajax({
  url: cart_ajax.ajaxurl,
  ...
})
```

Your javascript function will not work. **Here are some functional examples** of what you need to do:

- [WooCommerce - auto update total price when quantity changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137156/woocommerce-auto-update-total-price-when-quantity-changed)?
- [Wordpress passing ajax value to a specific page using Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678914/wordpress-passing-ajax-value-to-a-specific-page-using-wordpress/37685212#37685212)
- [Using AJAX With PHP on Your WordPress Site Without a Plugin](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/?trm=b&utm_expid=3606929-67.9mTA3ZaTSnSYStWsvDePTw.1)
- [How to use Ajax with your WordPress Plugin or Theme?](https://statenweb.com/uncategorized/how-to-use-ajax-with-your-wordpress-plugin-or-theme/)

Answer (score 6):

Since WooCommerce 2.6.0, released June 2016, WooCommerce cart page uses Ajax to update cart totals after clicking on Update cart button.

It's no longer needed to create your own Ajax call, the one assigned to Update cart button can be used.

I created a free plugin [Ajax Cart AutoUpdate for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-cart-autoupdate-for-woocommerce/) which updates cart page and mini cart after changing product quantity and provides some customization options for this process.

The most important thing is to set update delay. If user changes quantity again during this delay, it will be reset to full duration. If it's not implemented and you change quantity from 1 to 10 by clicking on increment button, it will trigger 9 Ajax calls instead of 1.

JQuery code is below, I suggest placing it in js file and enqueuing in dependency with jQuery, then it works with jQuery deferred:

```
var timeout;

jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: this works only on the cart page and not on any other page if you built cart by your self