# Display the total price for grouped products on the WooCommerce signle product page

Tags: woocommerce, product

I used [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64714045/display-the-total-price-on-the-woocommerce-single-product-page-with-the-original/64715593#64715593) which works perfectly for single product:

```
// Priority 31 is placed below the 'add to cart' button
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 31, 0 );

function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
    global $product;
    
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    $min_qnty = $product->get_min_purchase_quantity();
    $initial_price = floatval($price) * intval ($min_qnty);
    
    // leave the span class 'prezzo' as it is or it won't render the price
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price">%s %s</div>', __('Total:','woocommerce'), '<span class="prezzo">' . $currency_symbol . $initial_price . '</span>' );
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        // vars
        var price = <?php echo $price; ?>, 
            currency = '<?php echo $currency_symbol; ?>',
            quantity =  $( '[name=quantity]' ).val();
            
        var product_total = parseFloat( price * quantity );
        $( '#product_total_price .prezzo' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed( 2 ) );
            
        // On change
        $( '[name=quantity]' ).change( function() {
            if ( ! ( this.value < 1 ) ) {
                product_total = parseFloat( price * this.value );

                $( '#product_total_price .prezzo' ).html( currency + product_total.toFixed( 2 ) );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I would like to do the same thing for grouped products, but I'm not sure, how I should tackle this.

Any help is appreciated.